# How do i format strings in a generator?

Tags: python, string, generator, string-formatting

I want to format some values that are in a generator. When I try to do that I get an error:

```
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to generator.__format__
```

I tried different types of string formatting and nothing worked.

This is my code:

```py
def gen_secs():
    for i in range (60):
        yield i

def gen_minutes():
    for i in range (60):
        yield i

def gen_hours():
    for i in range (24):
        yield i

def gen_time(hours,minutes,seconds):
    yield (f'{hours:02}:{minutes:02}:{seconds:02}')

seconds = gen_secs()
minutes = gen_minutes()
hours = gen_hours()

gt = gen_time(hours,minutes,seconds)
while True:
    print(next(gt))
```

I want to get back all the different combinations of times in a day.

```
00:00:00
00:00:01
00:00:02
00:00:03
00:00:04
00:00:05
00:00:06
```

and so on...

Comment: Do *not* post links to code. All questions require a [mcve] in the question itself as formatted text.

Comment: Can you please paste the code directly in the question?  Linking to external sites is not allowed.

Comment: im sorry, i tried to post it directly but it kept saying indentation error for some reason.

Comment: Why not just put it in one generator with 3 nested loops?

Comment: assingment requirements

Comment: OK so leave as it is but change the `gen_time` to 3 nested loops on the generators. Also that's `while True:` probably wrong...

Comment: im sorry, i fail to follow, generators are a new subject to me. i don't get what you're trying to say.

Comment: i changed the gen_time function like so:                                                            def gen_time():
    seconds = gen_minutes()
    minutes = gen_minutes()
    hours = gen_hours()
    for hour in hours:
        for minute in minutes:
            for second in seconds:
                yield (f'{hour:02}:{minute:02}:{second:02}')
  
gt = gen_time()
while True:
    print(next(gt))

Comment: i get all the seconds but when it reaches 59 seconds i get an Stop iteration error

Comment: im sorry but i can't get code to paste properly here!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems here.

1. One is that your main generator `gen_time` yields one time so at best, eliminating all other issues, you will get only one time.
2. you pass to your `gen_time` the generator objects as arguments. Then you are formatting the string on the generator objects themselves and not their elements and hence your error.
3. You use a `while True` loop on the generator which will throw a `StopIteration` and break your program. I'm not sure that's what you want.

---

To solve this, taking in count point (1), you want some kind of loop wrapping your `yield` in the main generator. So, you could alter your main generator, `gen_time` to loop on the other generators. Like so:

```py
def gen_time():
    for hours in gen_hours():
        for minutes in gen_minutes():
            for seconds in gen_secs():
                yield (f'{hours:02}:{minutes:02}:{seconds:02}')
```

You could also write that more compact using the `yield from` construct:

```py
def gen_time():
    yield from (f'{hours:02}:{minutes:02}:{seconds:02}' for hours in gen_hours() for minutes in gen_minutes() for seconds in gen_secs())
```

Now considering point (3) you can change your main code to:

```py
for gt in gen_time():
    print(gt)
```